# Compare array and delete duplicate

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to compare 2 array of different dimension and then eliminate the duplicate and put the result on array called `tmp`

Here is the code

```java
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
HashSet<String> tmp = new HashSet<String>();

try 
{
    String query1="SELECT ID FROM Apps;";
        ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery(query1);
        while(rs.next())
        {
            list.add(rs.getString("ID"));
            tmp.add(rs.getString("ID"));
        }

        for(int i=0;i < check.size();i++)//ciclo  le checkbox selezionate
        {
                check.get(i);
                String query="UPDATE Apps SET Authorized='1' WHERE ID=" +check.get(i);//vado ad eseguire la query di update
                pr=con.prepareStatement(query);
                pr.executeUpdate();
                tmp.add(check.get(i).toString());
        }

        System.out.println(tmp);
```

The content of the two arrays is:

```
check -> [1, 2]
list -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The result I want is `tmp -> [3,4,5]`

but the console show `tmp -> [1,2,3,4,5]`

Comment: try deleting the = in j<=check.size()

Comment: @Nosrep ok, i try but it doesn't work

Comment: Assuming check Always contains elements present in tmp, iterate over the elements in check and remove these from tmp.

Comment: @trappski please give me the code!

Comment: @lucapellegrini I suggest you check the answer posted by P.Raber  and work from there. It's a clean an simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove duplicates like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Set<Integer> tmp = new HashSet<>();
    List<Integer> check = new ArrayList<>();
    check.add(1);
    check.add(2);
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
        list.add(i);
    }

    tmp.addAll(list);
    tmp.removeAll(check);
    System.out.println(tmp);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! This is the solution

Answer (score 2):

You could add everything to a `hashSet`

```
    HashSet<String> h = new HashSet<String>(); 

    // Adding elements into HashSet usind add() 
    h.add("Cats");
    h.add("Cats"):
    h.add("Dogs"); 

    System.out.println("List:" + h);
```

**Output**

```
List:[Dogs, Cats]
```

The hash set won't store any of the duplicates.

Comment: I try, but it show me tmp -> [1,2,3,4,5] when i want tmp->[3,4,5]

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    List<String> one = new ArrayList<>();
    one.add("one");
    one.add("two");
    one.add("three");
    one.add("in one");
    one.add("in two");

    List<String> two = new ArrayList<>();
    two.add("zero");
    two.add("one");
    two.add("two");
    two.add("four");
    two.add("not in one");
    two.add("in one");
    two.add("in two");

    // Depending on your needs create new or modify existing like one.addAll(two) and stream() from that.
    List<String> unique = one;
    unique.addAll(two);
    unique = unique.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println("Unique list: " + unique.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
    // Unique list: one,two,three,in one,in two,zero,four,not in one
  }
```

Comment: I want to delete the duplicate in array unique.. the code doesn't work well